# Am I considered to be a native speaker of English if I was born in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, language-exams

I'm applying for graduate colleges right now in the US. I was born there and did school till 7th grade and then shifted to India where I have been for the last 10 years until now. English is my first language, and I am a US citizen.

Am I considered a native English speaker for the purpose of admissions, or will I need to submit an English test certificate?

Comment: If it's your first language, yes. Citizenship and country of birth have nothing to do with it. Also, this question has nothing to do with academia so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @astronat I assume there is an unwritten "for the purpose of university admissions" in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, each university will set its own policies regarding who counts as native speaker and who needs to provide a test certificate to prove their competence.

I would be very surprised if "place of birth" counts as evidence for language proficiency. Being a US citizen might suffice, but I would not take this for granted, as English isn't officially the official language.

Having completed either school education or your undergraduate at an English speaking institution is a very commonly accepted criterion; and here I would expect that it is taken for granted that a US school or university is English speaking. However, even if your school or university in India taught in English, it may be cumbersome to prove this to admissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My institute of study does have English as the only method of instruction so I hope that does work for admissions.